# Find the difference between two dates/times

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite

I generate and insert a time and date into my SQLite3 database in Python with the following command:

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO ActiveTable (IDPK, time) VALUES (NULL, datetime('now', 'localtime'))")
```

The time is stored into the database in an INTEGER field with the format:

> 2016-07-18 08:58:48

I think that the value is actually stored as a TEXT since Sqlite3 works with type affinity, INTEGER is just left over code that I will probably change.

My goal is to query my database to get this value from a SELECT operation, and then find the difference compared to the current time using python's native time and date modules. My final goal is to have time difference from original insert to now represented *similarly* to this:

> 2d:1h:5m

To be inserted into the Database in a new field called TimeDiff.

Is this possible using time, date, or datetime in python? I'm having trouble with the syntax for these modules.

Comment: Subtracting two `datetime`s gives you a `timedelta` in python -- if that's what you are after.

Comment: +1 This ended up being perfect for the solution I needed and I used this method. Accepted other answer because he answered my question as asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

day1 = datetime.strptime("2016-07-18 08:58:48","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
day2 = datetime.strptime("2016-02-18 07:58:48","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(day1 -day2)
```

Output:

```
151 days, 1:00:00
```